# The variable name '@userid2' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: vb.net

This is my first time asking a question here. I am working on a project in which I have to update a table and also insert into another table using a transaction.

The insert part of the transaction block will come from the content of a selected gridview row.

The error I am getting is:

> The variable name '@userid2' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

How can I resolve this error?

This is my code:

```
  Protected Sub btnmodifyaccessdepot_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnmodifyaccessdepot.Click
        Using con As New SqlConnection(ConString)
            con.Open()
            Dim sqlTran As SqlTransaction = con.BeginTransaction()
            Dim command As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
            command.Transaction = sqlTran

        Try

            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Rhema_TechnicalAccess set Active=@Active,Requester= @Requester,Approver=@Approver,Issuer=@Issuer where userid=@userid"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", lblactiveadd.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Requester", lblrequesterAdd.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Approver", lblapproveradd.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Issuer", lblisssueradd.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid", lblselecteduserid.Text)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()



            For Each row As GridViewRow In gridadddepot.Rows
                If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                    Dim chkdepots As CheckBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("chkdepots"), CheckBox)
                    If chkdepots.Checked Then
                        Dim lbldepot As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lbldepot"), TextBox)



                        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Rhema_TechnicalAccessDepot VALUES(@userid2,@Depot,@Access,@TechnicalAccessID)"
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid2", lblselecteduserid.Text)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depot", lbldepot.text)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Access", lbluseraccessAdd.Text)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@technicalaccessid", lbltechnicalaccessid.Text)
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            sqlTran.Commit()


            lblmessage2.Text = "Both records were written to database."
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblmessage2.Text = ex.Message

            Try
                sqlTran.Rollback()
            Catch exRollback As Exception
                lblmessage2.Text = exRollback.Message
            End Try
        End Try
    End Using
         End Sub
```

Comment: You should create first parameters outside of `For Each` loop and then add values to them inside the loop.

Comment: As JohnyL wrote, you should create the parameters before the loop with the appropriate `New SqlParameter` constructor, remembering to declare the size of strings, and change the .Value of each parameter inside the loop. Also, please avoid AddWithParameter: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Code like this is the result of writing code without a clear idea of what it's supposed to do. Not only do you need to move the creation and addition of the parameters outside the loop, you need to move the `ExecuteNonQuery` call inside the loop. How does it make sense to go through all the rows of the grid and change the parameters each time and then only call `ExecuteNonQuery` once after the last change? Why would that insert any but the last row?

Comment: A better option would be to populate a `DataTable` with all the data, then create a data adapter and set its `InsertCommand` appropriately. You can then save the lot with one call to `Update`. For an example, [click here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&p=3112830&viewfull=1#post3112830).

Comment: @jmcilhinney Please can you please edit my code for me to get what i want to achieve. am at a lost and a newbie. Thank you in adavnce

Comment: You are overwriting the command.CommandText so only the second command will execute.

Comment: or just issue a command.Parameters.Clear() during each loop :)